# NVIDIA driver not loading in Dell g3-3590 Ubuntu 21.04 nvidia-driver-470

Tags: nvidia, dell

Recently my nVIDIA card stopped working in ubuntu 21.04.
I noticed constant CPU use and top showed modprobe using 44.5% CPU at all times.

Furhter investigation with `udevadm monitor` revealed the following scenario repeatedly:

```
UDEV  [601.231746] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [601.234197] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [601.314627] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia (drivers)
UDEV  [601.332429] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia (drivers)
KERNEL[601.590924] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[601.591569] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia (drivers)
KERNEL[601.591594] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia (drivers)
KERNEL[601.592254] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
```

dmesg revealed the following:

```
[  942.115453] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 511
[  942.115458] NVRM: This is a 64-bit BAR mapped above 4GB by the system
               NVRM: BIOS or the Linux kernel, but the PCI bridge
               NVRM: immediately upstream of this GPU does not define
               NVRM: a matching prefetchable memory window.
[  942.116045] NVRM: This may be due to a known Linux kernel bug.  Please
               NVRM: see the README section on 64-bit BARs for additional
               NVRM: information.
[  942.116047] nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
[  942.116069] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
[  942.116070] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
[  942.116556] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 511
```

Again, this repeats conmtinuously.

I really don`t have a clue how to fix it. GPU work flawlessly in Windows 10.

Comment: Looking at dmesg I found the following:

`[    1.238820] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)`

`[    1.238828] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)`

`[    1.239115] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: pci_alloc_irq_vectors err -22`

Comment: This problem is old. I just found the exact same problem in a ubuntu-bug mailing list post:
https://ubuntu-bugs.narkive.com/eINzSDzw/bug-1742112-new-nvidia-graphics-card-failed-to-initialized

Answer (score 0):

Have you found the solution yet?

I get the feeling this only affects the Dell G3 3590, as none of the solutions Ive found works. I have the exact same model and have the same problem. It also fails on Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried so many things spending over a week full time trying all sorts. I have found that Mint 19.3 works with 450 version of the drivers. I'm guessing Ubuntu 19 will too. It looks to me like a kernel bug, https://ubuntu-bugs.narkive.com/eINzSDzw/bug-1742112-new-nvidia-graphics-card-failed-to-initialized

Id really love to get this working properly.

Comment: The problem is that it worked quite well in ubuntu 20.04 until last june. Right now, I just purge the nvidia drivers and work with intel in ubuntu and switch to win10 for games.